# Put colour on a popup/message in powershell

Tags: powershell, deployment, system-administration

I want to put in red some words to test a msg that i will deploy/activate when i connect remotely to a pc.
I have tried placing at the begining:

Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{ ContinuationPrompt = 'Red' }
powershell -WindowStyle hidden -Command "& {[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms');...

It doesnt work.

And putting the function foregroundcolor at but gives me error.

powershell -ForegroundColor Red -WindowStyle hidden -Command "& {[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms'); ...

This is the code,the message pops and works well, i just want to put colour on the text.
I would like to put the words "please dont touch your keyboard or mouse" in red or if its not posible the whole text in red.

powershell -WindowStyle hidden -Command "& {[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms'); [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('IT department has connected to your PC please dont touch your keyboard or mouse, thank you','TEST/Message')}"

Comment: You can't change the font or fontcolor of a messagebox. You can however create your own window and change it so it looks like a messagebox (a messagebox is just a normal window with some elements in it like text and a button).

Comment: Ty, i wanted to do it as simple as possible its weird that such simple option isnt allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't change the font color in MessageBox. However, you can use a warning icon, like so:

```
powershell -WindowStyle hidden -Command "& {
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms');
[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('IT department has connected to your PC please dont touch your keyboard or mouse, thank you','TEST/Message',[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK,[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Stop)
}"
```

[image: TEST/Message]

Comment: Ty ill keep trying to get a solution but this works too.

Comment: then I advise you to pay attention to this decision: 
https://superuser.com/questions/1270122/how-to-colorize-specific-strings-in-powershell-textbox The approach is different from yours, a full-fledged form is drawn there.

Answer (score 1):

As u guys suggested i created a new window and centered it , im able to put the text in red but cant make it bigger or center it in the text box but it works.So solved.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Width = 200
$Form.Height = 200

$StatisticsBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$StatisticsBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(30, 30)
$StatisticsBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(120, 100)
$StatisticsBox.MultiLine = $True
$StatisticsBox.ScrollBars = "Horizontal"
$StatisticsBox.ReadOnly = $True
$StatisticsBox.Font = "Lucida Console"
$StatisticsBox.BackColor = "White"
$Form.Controls.Add($StatisticsBox)

$StatisticsBox.SelectionColor = 'Red'
$StatisticsBox.Text = "`r`nSE HA CONECTADO EL DEPARTAMENTO DE INFORMÁTICA`r`n" + $StatisticsBox.AppendText("NO TOCAR RATON NI TECLADO GRACIAS") + "`r`n" +$StatisticsBox.Text


# Calculamos el centro de la pantalla.
$screenWidth = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
$screenHeight = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
$centerX = ($screenWidth - $Form.Width) / 2
$centerY = ($screenHeight - $Form.Height) / 2

# Ejecutamos la ventana al medio
$Form.StartPosition = 'Manual'
$Form.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($centerX, $centerY)

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
$Form.Dispose()
```