# I need to show a disclaimer file (.TXT) center vertically and horizontally of the screen in red

Tags: powershell, text, center

I need to show a disclaimer file (.TXT) center vertically and horizontally of the screen in red.

```
$ConfigPath = '.\config.json'
$DisclamerPath = '.\DISCLAIMER.TXT' # *** Disclaimer path ***
IF (Test-Path -Path $ConfigPath -PathType Leaf)
{
    $Content = Get-Content '.\config.json' | ConvertFrom-Json
    IF ($Content.Config.First)
    {
        IF (Test-Path -Path $DisclamerPath -PathType Leaf)
        {
            $DISCL = Get-Content -Path $DisclamerPath
            FOREACH ($LINE IN $DISCL)
            {
                #I try some function like : WriteColor-Core -Text $LINE -Color red 
                #I try directly Write-Host $LINE -BackgroundColor DarkYellow -ForegroundColor Black
                                #I try a function like : centred_text
                $LINE # Error section
            }
            $null = Read-Host ' '
        }
        ELSE
        {
            Write-Host 'The disclaimer file not exist.' -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Black
        }   

        $Content.Config.First = $false # no quotes otherwise it is interpreted as string
        $Content | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content '.\config.json' -Encoding utf-8
        pause
    }
    ELSE
    {
        Write-Host 'This file has already been opened for the first time !'
        pause
    }
}
ELSE
{
    Write-Host 'The config file not exist.' -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Black
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
    RETURN
}
```

Here a disclaimer example :

> LEGAL DISCLAIMER
>
> This Sample Code is provided for the purpose of illustration only and
> is not intended to be used in a production environment.  THIS SAMPLE
> CODE AND ANY RELATED INFORMATION ARE PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY
> OF ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO
> THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR A
> PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  We grant You a nonexclusive, royalty-free right
> to use and modify the Sample Code and to reproduce and distribute the
> object code form of the Sample Code, provided that You agree: (i) to
> not use Our name, logo, or trademarks to market Your software product
> in which the Sample Code is embedded; (ii) to include a valid
> copyright notice on Your software product in which the Sample Code is
> embedded; and (iii) to indemnify, hold harmless, and defend Us and Our
> suppliers from and against any claims or lawsuits, including
> attorneys’ fees, that arise or result from the use or distribution of
> the Sample Code.
>
> This posting is provided "AS IS" with no warranties, and confers no
> rights. Use of included script samples are subject to the terms
> specified

I try some function like :

`WriteColor-Core -Text $LINE -Color red`

I try directly:

`Write-Host $LINE -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor Black`

I try a function like:

`centred_text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two basic options:

- Use a *GUI* library available for your platform, such as WinForms of WPF on Windows.

  - If you go this route, I suggest attempting an implementation yourself (WinForms will be easier), and then ask a focused question about your attempt if you get stuck.
- Use a *terminal*-based approach, which, however, hinges on the ability to create a full-screen terminal window on demand.

  - For sophisticated terminal-based formatting, you'll still need a library, such as [`Terminal.Gui`](https://github.com/gui-cs/Terminal.Gui), which isn't the easiest to use from PowerShell, however - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64232782/45375) for a basic example of its use.
  - A simplistic approach with limited formatting is shown below, and it assumes that you have *Windows Terminal* (`wt.exe`) installed.

```bash
# Windows-only, requires Windows Terminal.
# Displays a full-screen terminal window with vertically centered
# text printed in red, read from file .\disclaimer.txt
# Closes the window when the user presses Enter.
wt.exe --fullscreen -w $PID (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path -NoProfile {
  $lines = Get-Content .\disclaimer.txt
  $paddingLineCount = ([Console]::WindowHeight - $lines.Count) / 2
  if ($paddingLineCount -gt 0) {
    Write-Host -NoNewline ("`n" * $paddingLineCount)
  }
  $lines | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red
  Write-Host 'Press Enter to exit.'
  Read-Host
}
```

Comment: I tried "terminal.gui", but in PowerShell it's easy. But, in C#, there are bugs. I can't center the text in the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

If the color isn't a hard requirement you could always go for a simple `MessageBox`.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms') > $null

$Type = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK

$Icon = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Stop

$Body = @"
This Sample Code is provided for the purpose of illustration only...

This posting is provided "AS IS" with no warranties...
"@

$Title = "LEGAL DISCLAIMER"

$Result = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($Body,$Title,$Type,$Icon)
```

Also see, [Put colour on a popup/message in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76990748/put-colour-on-a-popup-message-in-powershell)